# Add Element to end of list in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Please help me with a code in Scheme basically what i need is as below
A function (append) which takes an atom and a list and adds the element to the end of the list.

Example:

```
(append 'A '(B C D)) -> (B C D A)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive approach would be:

```
(define (append atom lst)
  (if (empty? lst) 
      (list atom)
      (cons (car lst) (append atom (cdr lst)))))
```

usage:

```
> (append 'A '(B C D))
'(B C D A)
```

which is equivalent to

```
> (cons 'B (cons 'C (cons 'D (list 'A))))
'(B C D A)
```

Comment: maybe it's better not to use the standard name for it. This is widely known as "snoc" operation (a *reverse* of `cons`).

Comment: I totally agree, but I tried to stick to his question / example so that he can make sense of my answer.

Comment: The question looks like a homework and quacks like a homework, please don't spoon-feed the answer to the OP, it'd be better if you explained to him/her how to solve it by his own means without giving a straight answer

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: The "homework" tag was deprecated for a reason.  The general view of the community is that it is up to the OP to decide if it's homework or not in order to potentially limit the type of answers they are seeking.  For example, if it is marked homework then the answers should *lead* the person to the real answer as opposed to simply giving them the solution.  Without that tag, we no longer try to independently determine whether it's homework or not.  As such, uselpa's answer is perfectly valid and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add A on to the end of the list like this:

```
(append '(B C D) (list 'A)))
```

[Append](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/garbage/cs345/schintro-v13/schintro_43.html) needs a list argument as the first argument. The second argument doesn't have to be a list, but it will show up as `(B C D . A)` if you do `(append '(B C D) 'A))`

[My Example](http://codepad.org/EmvWkVRz)

Comment: I guess he needs to define procedure append, not use the build-in one.

Comment: @uselpa That might be the case. I posted this since the usage of append was incorrect in the example.

Comment: That's why I believe he's not supposed to use build-in procedure.